# extract header from a XMLTYPE column

Tags: xml, qxmlquery

I have an XMLTYPE column into a table which contains the value:

```
<header att1 = '1' att2 = '2' att3 = '3'>
    <tag1>val1</tag1>
    <tag2>val2</tag2>
    <tag3>val3</tag3>
</header>
```

And I want to extract into an XMLTYPE varaible

```
<header att1 = '1' att2 = '2' att3 = '3'/>
```

Can someone help me on this and maybe point me to a XMLQUERY training?

Thanks a lot,
Mikcutu.

Answer (score 0):

After I dig into XQuery, I found the answer:

```
select xmlquery(q'$ for $i in header 
                    return <header att1 = '{$i/@att1}' 
                                   att2= '{$i/@att2}' 
                                   att3= '{$i/@att3}'/>$' 
                    passing xml_column 
                    returning content) 
from table_name 
where condition = true;
```